# Background Image That Adjusts to Screen Width Constraining Proportions

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, scale

I would like to take an image I have (on it's own, it is not big enough to fit the screen width) and make it so that the image fits the screen width and adjusts the height accordingly to maintain proportions (width: 100% would not maintain the proportions, and I don't want it to be the full height of the screen since the page will be longer than the fold).

An example of what I want to achieve is with the blue background image in [this site](http://www.teehanlax.com/careers/) and you'll notice that the image itself does not move when the user scrolls, which is an effect I would also want to achieve and I believe would be achieved if the image is set as a background image.

Comment: Perhaps you could set it as position absolute at a low z index (Specifying top, left, right 0px and no height or bottom)?

Comment: Setting `width: 100%` on an image element will allow it to adjust its height automatically to preserve the proportions. Yet you also want the height not to exceed the viewport height, is that so?

Comment: Look up `background-size` and `background-attachment`.

Comment: No, I just was saying I can't set height:100% because my page is more than the viewport but it is okay if it exceeds the viewport. So does this mean all I need to do is set width:100%? Is that what the example site did and can I do that with a background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: contain;
background-position: top center;
```

should set you in the right direction. (Info on [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment), [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), and be aware of limited [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) in old IEs)

Comment: Wouldn't `background-size: cover` be better?

Comment: @Terry: cover will crop the image in one dimension to fill the other one, it sounds like that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I think background-size:cover worked. background-size:contain put the image at the height of the document but left whitespace on the side.